# How to solve "wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm. null returned for key: userId" error?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I'm using the command

```
WL.Client.getUserInfo("wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm", "userId");
```

to get the deviceId of the user and send it with other informations with an adapter.

The problem is that every time I update the app, even giving it another version number, I start getting the error below every time the code is called

```
wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm. null returned for key: userId
```

I can fix it if I call a `WL.JSONStore.destroy` inside `wlCommonInit()`, but of course I can't do it in a production environment.

The code to get deviceId is called twice, one of them is when I initialize the collections, inside "adapter..load..params".

Is that a way to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your authentication xml file ?

Comment: can you also share your code when initializing the JSONStore collections?

Comment: try `WL.Client.updateUserInfo ();` before calling `WL.Client.getUserInfo("wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm", "userId");`

Comment: AAhad, I'm using the standard one, didn't change it. Daniel Gonzalez, the JSONStore initialization wasn't really the problem, I removed the getUserInfo code from there, destroyed the JSONStore but the problem wasn't resolved. Kawinesh SK, thank you for the comment, it actually resolved the problem. Could you create an answer to this question explaining why this happens and giving more info so I can flag it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered my problem.

Actually, the method I was using to get deviceId uses a realm that lies in worklight server.
So, I need to set `connectOnStartup` to `true` or call `WL.Client.connect()`.
As my application need to work offline, I'm using the Apache Cordova `device.uuid` instead.